# Cannot run npm start reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, npm

This is my code on file server.js

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').parse()
}

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('layout', 'layouts/layout')
app.use(expressLayouts)
app.use(express.static('public'))

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true })
    const db = mongoose.connection
    db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
    db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Mongoose'))
app.use('/', indexRouter)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

When i try start the server, this error is shown to me

```
C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\Books\node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js:42      
  src.toString().split(NEWLINES_MATCH).forEach(function (line, idx) {
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\Books\node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js:42:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\Books\server.js:2:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! books@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the books@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mikae\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-18T03_27_14_460Z-debug.log
```

I try build a server with ReactJS, Express and MongoDB. This happen when i tried put MongoDB code on my file.

Comment: [`parse()`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#parse) needs a value passed to it to parse

Comment: @PatrickEvans So, whats value i need to put?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dotenv.parse is used with a buffer or a string containing your environment variables and **return an object**:

```
const envVariables = Buffer.from('API_KEY=apikey')
const config = dotenv.parse(envVariables) 
console.log(config); // {API_KEY: 'apikey'};
```

if you want to load a .env file, use dotenv.config:

```
dotenv.config();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){ require('dotenv').config() }
```

Comment: To help future readers as well as the person who asked the question originally, might you please [edit] your answer to explain a little how this code solves the problem?